# Is there a problem with extra aliyot on Simchat Torah?

Tags: halacha, simchat-torah

Follow up on related question [seven-aliyot-for-vzot-habracha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/seven-aliyot-for-vzot-habracha):

Gemarah Megilllah (Don't recall exact location) says that on Yom Tov falling on a weekday, we should have 5 aliyot and are not allowed to add extras.

If Chatan Torah and Chatan Breishit are included in the count of aliyot, then we have 7 aliyot in total. How would this be allowed? Are they included in the count or are they considered separate "special case" aliyot?

Comment: I don't think that the chatanim are regular aliyot.

Comment: Proving that gemara exists would greatly improve your question

Comment: For what it's worth, [Ma'aseh Rav 231](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33900&pgnum=42) says five are called on _Simchat Torah_: four for _ve-Zot ha-Berakhah_ (the fourth being the _Chatan Torah_), and the fifth is _Chatan Bereshit_. Also, [Ma'aseh Rav 132](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33900&pgnum=33) says that only seven are to be called on Shabbat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is addressed by the [Remo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) in [סימן תרסט - סדר יום שמחת תורה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_37.html#HtmpReportNum0024_L2), though he doesn't explain the rationale behind it.

> וְנָהֲגוּ עוֹד לְהַרְבּוֹת הַקְּרוּאִים לַסֵּפֶר תּוֹרָה, וְקוֹרִים פָּרָשָׁה אַחַת הַרְבֵּה פְּעָמִים וְאֵין אִסּוּר בַּדָּבָר (מִנְהָגִים וריב''ש סִימָן פ''ד). ‏

"The custom is to call up lots of people to the Torah [on Simchat Torah], and we read the Parsha [וְזֹאת הַבְּרָכָה] multiple times. And **there is no prohibition to do this**."

His sources are the מִנְהָגִים (not sure of that's a Sefer, or he means it's *everybody's* custom), as well as the [Rivash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_ben_Sheshet).

As to your statement:

> Gemarah Megilllah (Don't recall exact location) says that on Yom Tov falling on a weekday, we should have 5 aliyot and are not allowed to add extras.

It's already a Mishna in [פרק ד - משנה ב](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01101.html#HtmpReportNum0024_L2) that says:

> בְּרָאשֵׁי חֳדָשִׁים וּבְחֻלּוֹ שֶׁל מוֹעֵד, קוֹרִין אַרְבָּעָה. אֵין פּוֹחֲתִין מֵהֶן וְאֵין מוֹסִיפִין עֲלֵיהֶן, וְאֵין מַפְטִירִין בַּנָּבִיא. הַפּוֹתֵחַ וְהַחוֹתֵם בַּתּוֹרָה, מְבָרֵךְ לְפָנֶיהָ וּלְאַחֲרֶיהָ. זֶה הַכְּלָל, כָּל שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ מוּסָף וְאֵינוֹ יוֹם טוֹב, קוֹרִין אַרְבָּעָה. **בְּיוֹם טוֹב, חֲמִשָּׁה**. בְּיוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים, שִׁשָּׁה. בְּשַׁבָּת, שִׁבְעָה. אֵין פּוֹחֲתִין מֵהֶן, **אֲבָל מוֹסִיפִין עֲלֵיהֶן**, וּמַפְטִירִין בַּנָּבִיא. הַפּוֹתֵחַ וְהַחוֹתֵם בַּתּוֹרָה, מְבָרֵךְ לְפָנֶיהָ וּלְאַחֲרֶיהָ: ‏

The  עיקר תוי"ט already summarizes the various views on this:

> **מוסיפין כו'** אכולהו קאי דכיון שאסורין במלאכה מוסיפין עליהן דליכא למיחש משום בטול מלאכה. **ואחרים מפרשים** דנהי דאין פוחתין קאי אכולהו. אבל מוסיפין אשבת קאי בלחוד הר''ן. ועתוי''ט: (עיקר תוי"ט) ‏

The Gemara is the begining of the [3rd Perek .דף כא](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00885.html#HtmpReportNum0002_L5) and there I can't seem to find a source for your claim.

Comment: "... I can't seem to find a source for your claim." Maybe one of the statements attributed to R. Ishmael at the top of [23a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00885.html#HtmpReportNum0042_L2), "דתניא ביו"ט חמשה וביוה"כ ששה ובשבת שבעה אין פוחתין מהן **ואין מוסיפין עליהן** דברי ר' ישמעאל"?

Comment: @TamirEvan: Thanks - I missed that. Now the עיקר תוי"ט et el make sense.

Comment: (1) You're welcome.(2) Re: "מִנְהָגִים (not sure of that's a Sefer, or he means it's everybody's custom)": Based on the wording in _Darkhei Mosheh_ [669:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2789), it seems to be referring to a book. Based on [the Hebrew Wikipedia article on R. Isaac Tyrnau](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/יצחק_אייזיק_מטירנא#.D7.93.D7.A4.D7.95.D7.A1.D7.99_.D7.94.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.A8_.D7.95.D7.AA.D7.A4.D7.95.D7.A6.D7.AA.D7.95) it's probably referring to R. Isaac Tyrnau's _Sefer ha-Minhagim_.

Comment: אין פוחתין אבל מוסיפין עליהן. ומדברי רש"י ז"ל נראה דאכולהו הנך יומי קאי דכיון שאסורין במלאכה מוסיפין עליהן דליכא למיחש משום בטול מלאכה אבל אחרים מפרשים דנהי דאין פוחתין קאי אכולהו אבל מוסיפין עליהן אשבת בלחוד קאי אבל בשאר לא כדי שלא להשוותם לשבת שהוא עדיף מיניהו ובשבת דוקא דמוסיפין משום דליכא יומא דעדיף מיניה ויתיר ממנינא: That's the relevant Ran. Pshat does seem to be against it though. See also the Rama (Mappah and DM) in OC 282.